# Indexed Family with 2

Tags: real-analysis

$\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\bigcap_{m\in\mathbb{N}}A_{m,n} $

$A_{m,n} $ is the interval $\left[n-\frac{1}{m},n+m\right]$

And I have to figure out what the set is.

So far: I applied $\bigcap_{m\in\mathbb{N}}A_{m,n} $ first which changes the interval to $\left[n,n+1\right]$

Then applying $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ to this new interval gives the set of natural numbers.

Am I correct in this thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Granted that we take $\mathbb{N}$ to be the set $\{\, 1 \,,2 \,,3 \,, \ldots \,\}$ (thus not includning $0$).

First note that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have

$\bigcap_{m \in \mathbb{N}} [n -\tfrac{1}{m}, n+m] \subset \bigcap_{m \in \mathbb{N}} [n -\tfrac{1}{m}, n+1].$

Next note that $n \in [n -\tfrac{1}{m} , n+1]$ for all $m$, but as soon we get a number $x<n$, we can always find an $m \in \mathbb{N}$ with $x<n -\tfrac{1}{m}$, so

$\forall x (x < n \to x \notin \bigcap_{m \in \mathbb{N}} [n -\tfrac{1}{m}, n+1]).$

Hence $\bigcap_{m \in \mathbb{N}} [n -\tfrac{1}{m}, n+1] = [n,n+1]$, for all $n$.

Now

$\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcap_{m \in \mathbb{N}} [n -\tfrac{1}{m}, n+m] = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left( \bigcap_{m \in \mathbb{N}} [n -\tfrac{1}{m}, n+m] \right) = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} ([n, n+1]) = [1, \infty)$

is clear.

Notice that $[n,n+1] \ne \{n \,, n+1 \},$ a misperception that was maybe your reason to put the last sum identical the naturals?

Comment: Ahh okay, that is definitely where I must have made the misconception.  Would I be able to ask you one more question?  What if the order of things change and it is now

$\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ 

Can I apply the intersection first or do I always start at the inner most function?

Comment: In general we can't simply switch the order $\bigcap$ and $\bigcup$. Take the intervals $\{\,[n-m,n]\,\}_{n,m \in \mathbb{N}}$, for instance; $\bigcap_n \bigcup_m [n-m,n] = (- \infty, 1]$, while $\bigcup_m \bigcap_n [n-m,n]  = \varnothing$. Allthough in our example with $A_{n,m}$ defined as above this seems to work!

Comment: Okay thank you.  Any chance you have any input on this question as well? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/944731/unions-and-intersections-of-indexed-family