# Unions and Intersections of Indexed Family

Tags: real-analysis

$\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\bigcup_{m\in\mathbb{N}}A_{m,n} $

$A_{m,n} $ is the interval $\left[n-\frac{1}{m},n+m\right]$

So far I have:

$\bigcup_{m\in\mathbb{N}}A_{m,n} $ = $\left[n-1,\infty\right)$

From here I'm confused on how to treat $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ on this new interval.

It seems to come out to $\infty$

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think that the union gives $\cup A_{m,n}=(n,\infty)$. But it doesn't change your reasoning, and it seems correct: the intersection of overlapping sets should be the "smaller" set. I'm inclined to say that resulting set is not $\{\infty\}$ (because it doesn't have sense), but it is empty (because infinity is not defined in the reals...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all $n \in \mathbb{N} \,\, (= \{\,1 \,,2 \,, \ldots \,\} \,)$ we have 
$$
\bigcup_{m \in \mathbb{N}} [n-\tfrac{1}{m},n+m] = [n-1, \infty).
$$

Hence 
$$
\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup_{m \in \mathbb{N}} [n-\tfrac{i}{m},n+m] = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left( \bigcup_{m \in \mathbb{N}} [n-\tfrac{i}{m},n+m] \right) = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} [n-1, \infty )
$$

Now, suppose 
$$x \in \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} [n-1, \infty )$$.
Clearly there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $N -1 > x$, which is to say that $x \notin [N-1, \infty)$, that is
$$x \notin  \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} [n-1, \infty )$$
contradicting the assumtion.

We get $$\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} [n-1, \infty ) = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup_{m \in \mathbb{N}} [n-\tfrac{1}{m},n+m] = \varnothing.$$

Comment: Thank you, it was that second part that was really getting me.  I appreciate the help